# How to compare to directory names and enter the one that is the highest version

Tags: bash

I have two version of tcpdump in the same subdirectory.

tcpdump-4.1.1 and tcpdump-4.3.0

How can I write a bash function to return the highest version?

***Edit:***

I've got it working now. Here's the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Function to get the latest version of the directory
function getLatestDirVer {
    latestDIR=$(ls -v $1* | tail -n 1)
    stringLen=`expr length "$latestDIR"`
    stringLen=$(($stringLen-1))
    latestDIR2=`expr substr $latestDIR 1 $stringLen`
    echo $latestDIR2
}

# Main function
echo $(getLatestDirVer tcpdump)
```

Here's the ouptut

```
[luke@machine Desktop]$ ./latestDIRversion.sh 
tcpdump-4.3.0
```

The tcpdump-4.1.1 and tcpdump-4.3.0 directories are in the Desktop directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `ls`. You can use the `-v` flag to sort by version numbers in filename lowest to highest:

```
ls -v tcpdump* | tail -n 1
```

---

***EDIT:***

So it turns out, I completely mis-read your question. I thought you were interested in the filenames, but you're actually interested in the directories. You can add the following to your `~/.bashrc`, I think it will work for you:

```
getLatestDirVer () {
    for i in $(find ./* -type d | sort --version-sort); do :;done
    cd "$i"
}
```

Comment: This is kinda working, but it's saying 'tcpdump-4.3.0:'.

Here's my code,
    #!/bin/bash
    # Function to get the latest version of the directory
    function getLatestDirVer
    {
 latestDIR=$((ls -v $1*| tail -n 1))
 stringLen=`expr length $latestDIR`
 $stringLen = $($stringLen - 2)
 $latestDIR=`expr substr $latestDIR 1 $stringLen`
 echo $latestDIR
    }
    
    # Main function
    out=$(getLatestDirVer tcpdump)
    echo $out
    
    echo "Done"

but it's saying
./latestDIRversion.sh: line 6: ls -v tcpdump*| tail -n 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "tcpdump*| tail -n 1")

Comment: @lukegjpotter: Please see the edit I've made to my answer. Everytime you type `getLatestDirVer`, you should navigate to the latest directory. Hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -1 tcpdump*|sort -rn|head -1
```

Comment: I used the other guy's answer, but your ls command works fine too, thanks.